# How to Use Excel to Link Data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to figure out how to use different spreadsheets to answer certain questions in another.

For example, A question in the main spreadsheet in a particular column would be "Is this firm a member of this association?"

I would like to be able to put in a formula that pulls data from the "firm members" spreadsheet and put a value of "Yes" or "No" in the cell next to the name of the firm.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter a sorted list of `{x}` members in a workbook named "members" on a worksheet named "members".

Enter a name in cell `A1` of a 2nd workbook (the name makes no difference). Enter the formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(A1,[members.xlsx]members!$A$1:$A${x},1)=A1,"Yes","No")
```

In cell `B1` of the 2nd workbook, which will display "yes" or "no" based on a match (once you do the following substitution).

In the above formula, substitute the number of the last cell of the sorted list in the "members" workbook for the `{x}`, e.g., `:$A${x}` is changed to `:$A$16` if the list has 16 members in `A1:A16`.